# Write list of list to file and then retrieve it from the file as a list of list

Tags: python, list, readfile

I apologize for the confusing title, I am myself confused.

Right now I am working on a program where I create a list whose elements are lists. I then write each element to a file.

An example would be that I create list **food** with elements that are specific food items that are lists that contain information about the item itself.

Right now my program will write each element of food to a file, for instance if I have

```
food = [banana, beans]
```

My output in food.txt will appear as

```
['Banana' , .54 , 'No' , 'Food']
['Beans' , 1.39, 'Yes', 'Food']
```

Where the first is the list **banana** and the second is the list **beans** from my list **food**.

What I want is when I run the program again for these lists to be replaced into **food** before I do anything else. I know that I can create a list from a file by

```
inFile.readline()
```

However, this does not seem to yield the correct result. Therefore, my question is how to read the lists from the file and put them back in my **food** list exactly as they were before I closed the program. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> banana, beans = ['Banana' , .54 , 'No' , 'Food'], ['Beans' , 1.39, 'Yes', 'Food']
>>> food = [banana, beans]
>>> with open('data', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(food, f)


>>> with open('data', 'rb') as f:
        print pickle.load(f)


[['Banana', 0.54, 'No', 'Food'], ['Beans', 1.39, 'Yes', 'Food']]
```

Comment: Ok, I have gotten this to work and it works exactly as I had hoped. The only issue is that pickle.load(f) will return an error if the file is empty, so I have to add an item to the file, then it will run just fine. Is there any way to account for the file being empty and then not running the pickle.load?

Comment: @only_gad simply use a `try`/`except` to catch that error if it occurs